# How to fix "Undefined Method total_pages"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, will-paginate

I am setting up a search functionality in my Ruby On Rails application. I want users to search for a particular topic and be able to display the results. However, if there is no results pending, it should display a validation.

I have currently tried researching and adding different code such as adding `@topic.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 2)`
and

trying this:

`Topic.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(3)`

topics_controller:

```
def index
 if params[:search].present?
   @topics = Topic.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
   flash[:notice] = "No records found based on the search." if @topics.blank?
 else
   @topics = Topic.all
   flash[:notice] = "No records found in Database." if @topics.blank?
 end
end
```

index.html.erb:

`<div>
    <%= will_paginate @topic, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</end>`

I expect as a validation message to appear. But instead, I have the following error:

**undefined method `total_pages'

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqjtu.jpg)

I understand this error because of the pagination being added but not sure how to overcome this.

Comment: Could you add the full error?

Comment: @JoseManuel I have updated my question with a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is not your pagination but the `else` branch where you are not paginating `@topics`. Will_paginate can't create the pagination links.

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @topics = Topic.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    flash[:notice] = "No records found based on the search." if @topics.blank?
  else
    @topics = Topic.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5) #add this
    flash[:notice] = "No records found in Database." if @topics.blank?
  end
end
```